# Extracted pdf text is not getting displayed in console

Tags: java, tabula

I am trying to extract the pdf text using Tabula. But the code has no errors but when i run the extracted pdf text does not get displayed in console. Could some one help.

I have been using PDFBox and after doing some research, i have found that tabula is new and wanted to try it.

```
File file = new File(pdfFilePath);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
ObjectExtractor oe = new ObjectExtractor(document);
Page page = oe.extract(1) //1st page
TextStripper textStripper = new TextStripper(document,1);
System.out.println(textStripper.getText(document));

output of pdf text
```

Comment: Maybe the PDF doesn't support text extraction. Try opening it with Adobe Reader and then do copy & paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the page variable. Try the following code.

```
File file = new File(pdfFilePath);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
ObjectExtractor oe = new ObjectExtractor(document);
Page page = oe.extract(1); // 1st page

for (TextElement textElement: page.getText()) {
  System.out.print(textElement.getText());
}
```